# How Do I Select Nth-Child Of A Node In XML Document Tree With PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Consider the following example:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="3" yahoo:created="2014-03-28T13:30:16Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
<results>
<strong class="js-mini-profile-stat" title="8">8</strong>
<strong class="js-mini-profile-stat" title="0">0</strong>
<strong class="js-mini-profile-stat" title="1,643">1,643</strong>
</results>
</query>
```

I want to get that "strong" node with value of 1,643

I'm doing it like this:

```
$tw=$_GET["tw"];

function twitter($tw) {
$furl = file_get_contents("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22https://twitter.com/".$tw."%22%20AND%20xpath=%22//a[@class=%27js-nav%27]/strong%22&format=xml");

$api = simplexml_load_file($furl);
$followers = $api->results->strong[3];
return $followers;
}
```

But obviously, it returns error. There are 3 strong nodes, how do I select the third one? 
Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the 3rd `<strong>` node, do:

```
$followers = $api->results->strong[2];
```

because indices start at `0`.

If you want to select the element by its title instead of its position, use `xpath`:

```
$followers = $api->xpath("//strong[@title = '1,643']")[0]; // with PHP >= 5.4
```

or with PHP < 5.4:

```
$followers = $api->xpath("//strong[@title = '1,643']");
$followers = $followers[0];
```

see it working: https://eval.in/128263